# Including the Expat library in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, include, expat-parser

I've downloaded a copy of Expat 2.0.1, which is basically a bunch of .h and .c files (see the complete directory in the screenshot below).

[image]

To add the library to the VS 2013 project I'm working on, I went to Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories and added the path of the 2.0.1 folder shown in the screenshot to the "Include Directories" field. This gets rid of all the intellisense errors, but when I build the project I get a bunch of linker errors that are complaining about unresolved symbols (eg `XML_ParserCreate`, which is a function from the Expat library). I can right-click on these symbols and peek the definition, so it seems like everything is "hooked up" correctly. How can I get the linker to stop complaining? There doesn't seem to be any libraries I can add to the Linker section of the configuration. Do I need to use `Makefile.MPW` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the source, you have to create the library yourself, see [MicrosoftDocs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp.md). BTW MPW is a Mac file.